# Access child token in JSON

Tags: json, linq, linq-to-sql, json.net

In the below JSON I was trying to access the second array in the header.Basically "Node", "Percentage", "Time","File System" needs to captured as I will have to insert into SQL.My code is giving the complete array of header.

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            List<string> childTokens = new List<string>();
            foreach (var childToken in jsonObject.Children<JProperty>())
                childTokens.Add(childToken.Name);

           foreach (string childToken in childTokens)
        {
            if (jsonObject[childToken] is JObject)
            {
                JObject jObject = (JObject)jsonObject[childToken];
                var jProperty = jObject.Children<JProperty>();

            try

                {


                    if (jProperty.LastOrDefault(x => x.Name == "header") != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var headerValue in jProperty.LastOrDefault(x => x.Name == "header").Value.Children())
                            table.Columns.Add("[" + headerValue.ToString() + "]");
                        table.Columns.Add("[ID]");
                        table.Columns.Add("[comments]");
                    }
```

JSON sample:

```
 "DISK" : {
      "alarm_count" : 5,
      "column_width" : [
         12,
         14,
         16,
         14
      ],
      "header" : [
         [
            "",
            "Max Disk Usage",
            3
         ],
         [
            "Node",
            "Percentage",
            "Time",
            "File System"
         ]
      ] }
```

I can have number of arrays in header .. don't want to hardcode it.. I should be always be able to pick the last array in header child token..Please advise .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your json snippet was valid and is part of an object like:

```
{
  "DISK": {
    "alarm_count": 5,
    "column_width": [
      12,
      14,
      16,
      14
    ],
    "header": [
      [
        "",
        "Max Disk Usage",
        3
      ],
      [
        "Node",
        "Percentage",
        "Time",
        "File System"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

You could do this:

```
JObject obj = ...;
var secondHeader = obj["DISK"]["header"].Last();
```

Comment: Hi , I can have n number of arrays in the header .. I don't want to hard code.. I want to pick the last item always in the header.. thanks

Comment: You always have linq to help you out with that.

Comment: Yes, I tried LINQ to get the header elements .. looks like I am missing some  thing in order to get the last array of header element.Thanks..Please advise

Comment: Right... I edited my answer to address your problem when you first brought it up.

Comment: if (jProperty.LastOrDefault(x => x.Name == "header") != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var headerValue in jProperty.LastOrDefault(x => x.Name == "header").Value.LastOrDefault().Children())
                                table.Columns.Add("[" + headerValue.ToString() + "]");
                            table.Columns.Add("[ModuleID]");
                            table.Columns.Add("[UseCaseID]");
                        }        -- Not giving the second/last array..